# Django Model Design using GenericForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Scheme model that can have 2 rewards assign to it only, one for a member of the scheme and the other for their friend.

Below is how I have design the model for this, but now I'm starting to question the design, Is the link to Scheme and rewards incorrect? Should I have the relationship the other way around on abstract reward instead?

**Scheme:**

```
class Scheme(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    participant_reward_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,
                                                        editable=False,
                                                        related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_as_participant',
                                                        null=True, blank=True
    )
    participant_reward_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    participant_reward = generic.GenericForeignKey('participant_reward_content_type', 'participant_reward_object_id')

    friend_reward_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,
                                                   editable=False,
                                                   related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_as_friends',
                                                   null=True, blank=True
    )
    friend_reward_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    friend_reward = generic.GenericForeignKey('friend_reward_content_type', 'friend_reward_object_id')
```

**Rewards:**

```
class AbstractReward(models.Model):
    """
    Abstract reward common information shared for all rewards.
    """
    description = models.CharField(max_length="150")
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    #scheme = models.ForeignKey(Scheme, null=True,)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class SingleVoucherReward(AbstractReward):
    """
    Single-use coupons are coupon codes that can only be used once
    """
    pass

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'schemes'


class MultiVoucherReward(AbstractReward):
    """
    A multi-use coupon code is a coupon code that can be used unlimited times.
    """
    code = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    expiry = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'schemes'


class CustomReward(AbstractReward):
    """
    A reward class used when it can't be handled or they would like to
    handle reward fulfillment themselves.
    """
    pass

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'schemes'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend keeping it really simple - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

Given the similarity in data definitions of the 3 types of Reward I'd lose the inheritance altogether and just give it a type selection:

```py
class Reward(models.Model):
    SINGLE = 'Single'
    MULTI = 'Multi'
    CUSTOM = 'Custom'
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
                (SINGLE, 'Single'),
                (MULTI,  'Multi'),
                (CUSTOM, 'Custom'),
            )

    description = models.CharField(max_length="150")
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default=SINGLE)

    code = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    expiry = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

[Two Scoops of Django](https://django.2scoops.org/) - which is a great reference for how to approach things in Django - also recommends this approach.

This also means that you don't need the GenericForeignKey and can have simple foreign keys, massively reducing the complexity again:

```py
class Scheme(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    participant_reward = models.ForeignKey('Reward', null=True, blank=True)
    friend_reward = models.ForeignKey('Rewards', null=True, blank=True)
```

Built in stuff like the Django admin and ModelForms will just work out of the box with this approach.

Some may not like the verbosity of the [TYPE_CHOICES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices) but it is so simple and clear to maintain.

I also realize that you may end up with methods on the Reward class that have to modify behaviour for different types e.g.:

```
if self.type = CUSTOM:
   pass
```

but again this is very simple to maintain. You could use [Proxy Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) if the code starts to really diverge.

Some may argue that this is not 'Pythonic' but we are not handling pure python classes here, and besides the [Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) states as its third principle:

> Simple is better than complex.

Comment: Thanks DaveB, you comments are very interesting, reading Two Scoops of Django right now.

Comment: My only issue with this approach is different rewards have extended properties that don't necessary relate to each. This is why I have a abstract model for the base. I do like the idea of using selectors tho.

Comment: Proxy models, thats interesting I was not aware you could even do that, nice. The only catch is this "must inherit from exactly one non-abstract model class"

Answer (score 1):

You can make your `AbstractReward` not so abstract (and rename it to `BaseReward`), then `ForeignKey` to it and get actual reward type and object in some method. You will need to make an additional request, but I think it will be the same with `GenericForeignKey`.